# wsgi cookies - no middleware

Tags: wsgi

Sounds simple enough

```
def create_cookie():
        bag = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
        cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
        cookie['sessionid'] = ''.join(random.sample(bag,24))
        cookie['sessionid']['expires'] = 600
        return 'Set-Cookie: ', cookie.output().replace('Set-Cookie: ', '', 1)
```

cookie.output() is Set-Cookie: sessionid=YmsrvCMFapXk6wAt4EVKz2uU; expires=Sun, 14-Aug-2011 21:48:19 GMT

```
    headers.append(('Content-type', 'text/html'))
    headers.append(('Content-Length', str(output_len)))
    headers.append(create_cookie)
```

This is my response
('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/html'), ('Content-Length', '1204'), ('Set-Cookie', 'sessionid=YmsrvCMFapXk6wAt4EVKz2uU; expires=Sun, 14-Aug-2011 21:48:19 GMT')], 'html stuff')

This is what I get from envirion:
HTTP_COOKIE: sessionid=YmsrvCMFapXk6wAt4EVKz2uU

And when I click another link on my page, no more HTTP_COOKIE
Using the chrome dev console I can see the request cookie and the page header contains:
Cookie:: sessionid=YmsrvCMFapXk6wAt4EVKz2uU

Now, this bothers me a bit. First of all why does it have double :: ? I tried using 'Set-Cookie' instead of 'Set-Cookie: ' in the create_cookie function. Doing that I didn't get any HTTP_COOKIE at all from environ.

So after lots of searching in the web and everyone just talking middleware (don't suggest I use one please - I'm doing this to learn the wsgi) ... I've come up empty.

Comment: Nothing yet?
Basically I'm sending: ('Set-Cookie', 'sessionid=YmsrvCMFapXk6wAt4EVKz2uU; expires=Sun, 14-Aug-2011 21:48:19 GMT')

But getting this header: 
HTTP_COOKIE: : sessionid=hM2YOE5dSsVpa3QIRCLNjfwX

Why the extra ':' ?

Comment: oh, and I changed 'expires' to 'max-age' 10*60*1000 :S - still no luck though.

Comment: ok, seems that the correct way to do this is to just use 'Set-Cookie'. Not 'Set-Cookie: ' - now I get: HTTP_COOKIE: session=FZ25UL60bQP7yu93cEawtqro

Comment: Now correct me if I'm wrong but once I've sent the cookie to the browser it should always send that particular cookie to the server when making a request (as long as domain, path and all that stuff matches) in the form:
HTTP_COOKIE: cookie_name=something; other_params=whatever; ...

I'm not specifying any path or domain and I do get the HTTP_COOKIE right after I've created and sent it but next request to the same site ... no HTTP_COOKIE. I even read the HTTP_COOKIE and add a new 'Set-Cookie' to the headers, yet nothing.

I'm very confused now :S

Answer (score 2):

Invisible default behavior ftw...

After some intensive debugging I noticed that the following request didn't include the HTTP_COOKIE making it conclusively a problem on the browsers side of actually sending the cookie that I could find in the browser otherwise.

Some digging around revealed that the default path and domain behavior was spoiling my efforts , the difference between /action/login (where the cookie was set) and /display/data (where the cookie wasn't sent was fixed by setting the path in this case to '/'.

"yay"

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
return [tuple(line.split(': ',1)) for line in cookie.output().split('\r\n')]
```

This also works for multiple entries in cookie.
Of course, you need to use extend instead of append:

```
headers.extend(create_cookie())
```